# File Transfer On Windows 8 WiFi Direct

Tags: windows-8

I study on the Windows 8 and try create an App for transfer file between 2 PCs by the WiFi Direct.
Now I can let the app send text between 2 PCs.

SendText:

```
private async void SendText()
{
    string msg = SendMessageTextBox.Text;

    if (msg.Length > 0)
    {
        var msgLength = dataWriter.MeasureString(msg);
        dataWriter.WriteInt32(msg.Length);
        dataWriter.WriteString(msg);
        try
        {
            await dataWriter.StoreAsync();
            Debug.WriteLine("Send Message >>: " + msg + "\n");
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Send error: " + exc.Message + "\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Receive Text:

```
private async void ReceiveText(StreamSocket socket, DataReader reader)
{        
    uint initialLength = 5;

    try
    {
        await reader.LoadAsync(initialLength);
        uint msgLength = (uint)reader.ReadInt32();

        try
        {
            await reader.LoadAsync(msgLength);
            string message = reader.ReadString(msgLength);
            Debug.WriteLine(currentTime + " <<: " + message + "\n"); 

            ReceiveText(socket, reader);
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Error: " + exc.Message + "\n");
            socket.Dispose();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception exc)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Error: " + exc.Message + "\n");
        socket.Dispose();
    }
}
```

But I really confuse how to convert and transfer file, I spend lots time on it...

I know there are some methods in the DataReader and DataWriter class:

```
...
public IBuffer ReadBuffer(uint length);
public void ReadBytes(byte[] value);
public static DataReader FromBuffer(IBuffer buffer);
...
public void WriteBytes(byte[] value);
public void WriteBuffer(IBuffer buffer, uint start, uint count);
...
```

But how to convert file to stream and using what method to send and receive?

I try my best, but always fail, really make me paint...

Is someone give me some guide? Or a small sample?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an article (including a lib you can reuse) to help you transfer files with Wifi-Direct between 2 Windows 8 peers:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/stephe/archive/2013/12/11/win8-1-transfering-a-file-between-2-peers-using-wifi-direct-and-proximity-api.aspx

Hope it helps